# Weird problem in Laptop

Tags: startup

I should also tell here before starting my question that my laptop is under illegal Surveillance by corrupt Government officers. They can control it even when there is no Bluetooth, wifi chip and there is no way to connect to internet at all as a common user.

Well I have an 4 years old laptop and for last few days it was working file even now it does. The problem I am facing is that Its power button LED stop glowing and it does not turn for hours and hours on pressing the power button. It turn on looks like only when it have mood to Turn On.
So it is not, as I suspect, a hardware problem but being controlled at chip level by the hackers.
I want to get in detail of information is it possible for them to not let my laptop T/On at all in thier wish. Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn’t appear to be [Apple products-related](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Ajay, what kind of laptop are you using?

Comment: @Ajay This is a macOS focused site. If this laptop is a MacBook, then this site can help you. But you need to edit your question to provide _actual technical details_ like make, model and OS and not details on your perceived fears as to someone supposedly hacking your machine. Without actual technical details and with the bulk of your question expressing your perceived hacking nobody can help you. Post actual technical details and if on topic for aq macOS/Apple site this site _might_ be able to help you. Otherwise, sorry…

Comment: Nohilaide It is acer Gate NE46arS1 Linux mint

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update. Questions about non-Apple hardware running non-Apple OS' are off-topic here.